# How to use Group By in certain Select in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, group-by

I haven't used `Group By` that much before and always get an error when trying to group the following by the `UserID`

Error:

> Column 'Log.Version' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

How can I avoid this ? What I am trying to get is a count for each user with every user only appearing once for each tool instead of listing every usage separately.

My query (working except for the above + simplified for demo):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].Reporting_FetchUsage
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT      
        A.UserID, A.Tool, A.[Version], A.Note, A.[TimeStamp],
        B.ADesc, B.SDesc, B.DDesc, B.ALN
    FROM 
        Log A
    LEFT JOIN   
        EmployeeTable B ON B.NTID = A.UserID
    WHERE       
        A.[TimeStamp] > DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
        AND (A.Tool LIKE 'abc%'
             OR
             A.Tool LIKE 'def%'
             OR
             A.Tool LIKE 'ghi%')
        AND (B.DDesc = 'CB'
             OR
             B.DDesc = 'PS')
    GROUP BY    
        A.Tool, A.UserID
    ORDER BY    
        A.Tool, A.UserID
    FOR XML PATH('reporting'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
END
```

Comment: Include all the fields in your `GROUP BY` clause that are in your `SELECT` statement that are not being used in an aggregate.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. If you want aggregate data you MUST group by the non-aggregated columns. I would think you don't want most of the columns in the output. Which Note, timeStamp etc do you want in the result if you want those columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *What I am trying to get is a count for each user with every user only
>   appearing once for each tool instead of listing every usage
>   separately.*

If this is the case, I would expect to see a `count()` somewhere.  Perhaps this is closer to what you want:

```
SELECT l.UserID, l.Tool, e.ADesc, e.SDesc, e.DDesc, e.ALN,
       COUNT(*) as NumTools
FROM Log l LEFT JOIN 
     EmployeeTable e
     ON e.NTID = l.UserID
WHERE l.[TimeStamp] > DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()) AND
      (l.Tool LIKE 'abc%' OR l.Tool LIKE 'def%' or l.Tool LIKE 'ghi%') AND
      B.DDesc IN ( 'CB', 'PS')
GROUP BY l.UserID, l.Tool, e.ADesc, e.SDesc, e.DDesc, e.ALN,
ORDER BY l.Tool, l.UserID;
```

This assumes that the employee table does not have duplicates, with respect to the join conditions on the `Log`.

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is perfect. I had the count but forgot to mention in it in the post here, sorry for that. e only contains unique values so this works perfect. Thanks for the quick reply !

Answer (score 2):

Include all the fields in your `GROUP BY` clause that are in your `SELECT` statement that are not being used in an aggregate.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].Reporting_FetchUsage

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT      A.UserID,
                A.Tool,
                A.[Version],
                A.Note,
                A.[TimeStamp],
                B.ADesc,
                B.SDesc,
                B.DDesc,
                B.ALN
    FROM        Log A
    LEFT JOIN   EmployeeTable B
    ON          B.NTID = A.UserID
    WHERE       A.[TimeStamp] > DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
    AND         (
                    A.Tool LIKE 'abc%'
                    OR
                    A.Tool LIKE 'def%'
                    OR
                    A.Tool LIKE 'ghi%'
                )
    AND         (
                    B.DDesc = 'CB'
                    OR
                    B.DDesc = 'PS'
                )
GROUP BY    A.Tool, 
            A.UserID, 
            A.[Version],
            A.Note,
            A.[TimeStamp],
            B.ADesc,
            B.SDesc,
            B.DDesc,
            B.ALN
    ORDER BY    A.Tool, A.UserID
    FOR XML PATH('reporting'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')

END
```